# ML to predict input parameters

Tags: machine-learning

If you have a machine learning task, you are given a set of input parameters (features) and a output parameter (target). Based on a set of input+output pairs, you train a model and later use that model to predict the output (given the input).

My problem is somewhat different: I am given a set of input and output parameters (that part is identical), that have been recorded during a manifacturing process. (Acutually the input parameters are input values to a machine that produces some piece of equipment). I should suggest to the operators of the machine a set of the input parameters, that will most likely yield the best output parameters.

Q1: Is this type of problem also called machine learning?
Q2: If not, what are these types of problems called?

Comment: So, according to your understanding, what is the difference between ML (1st para) and your case (2nd para)? The fact that your case has more than one output parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be classed as Machine Learning ... *but* it would be better classified as **Neural Networks**. However, these both come under the umbrella term of **Artificial Intelligence**.